# Kubernetes - Kafka timeout to connect to zookeeper

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, strimzi

I am using Strimzi to deploy Kafka cluster on Kubernetes.
My zookepers has been running with 3 replicas but my kafkas pods are in CrashLoopBackOff status.

I take a look on the logs and I saw in Kafka logs :

```
2023-03-02 14:37:39,092 INFO Opening socket connection to server logs-zookeeper-client/10.233.20.91:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn) [main-SendThread(logs-zookeeper-client:2181)]
2023-03-02 14:37:39,354 INFO SSL handler added for channel: [id: 0x49e082ec] (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNetty) [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1]
2023-03-02 14:37:55,076 INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient) [main]
2023-03-02 14:37:57,189 WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 20114ms for session id 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn) [main-SendThread(logs-zookeeper-client:2181)]
2023-03-02 14:37:57,190 WARN An exception was thrown while closing send thread for session 0x0. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn) [main-SendThread(logs-zookeeper-client:2181)]
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SessionTimeoutException: Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 20114ms for session id 0x0
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1258)
```

But if I list my services and pods in my namespace, I can see the service with the right IP:Port that kafka try to reach (logs-zookeeper-client/10.233.20.91:2181) :

```
NAME                                            READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE
pod/logs-kafka-0                                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8 (26s ago)   19m
pod/logs-kafka-1                                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8 (26s ago)   19m
pod/logs-kafka-2                                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8 (15s ago)   19m
pod/logs-zookeeper-0                            1/1     Running            0             19m
pod/logs-zookeeper-1                            1/1     Running            0             19m
pod/logs-zookeeper-2                            1/1     Running            0             19m
pod/strimzi-cluster-operator-677bf6869f-w9v6f   1/1     Running            0             16h

NAME                            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                               AGE
service/logs-kafka-bootstrap    ClusterIP   10.233.30.141   <none>        9091/TCP,9092/TCP,9093/TCP            19m
service/logs-kafka-brokers      ClusterIP   None            <none>        9090/TCP,9091/TCP,9092/TCP,9093/TCP   19m
service/logs-zookeeper-client   ClusterIP   10.233.20.91    <none>        2181/TCP                              19m
service/logs-zookeeper-nodes    ClusterIP   None            <none>        2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP            19m

NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/strimzi-cluster-operator   1/1     1            1           16h

NAME                                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/strimzi-cluster-operator-677bf6869f   1         1         1       16h
```

kubectl describe pod/logs-kafka-0 :

```
Name:             logs-kafka-0
Namespace:        logs
Priority:         0
Service Account:  logs-kafka
Node:             k8s-eu-de-worker-01/141.95.97.153
Start Time:       Thu, 02 Mar 2023 09:24:15 +0100
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=logs
                  app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=strimzi-cluster-operator
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=kafka
                  app.kubernetes.io/part-of=strimzi-logs
                  statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=logs-kafka-0
                  strimzi.io/cluster=logs
                  strimzi.io/component-type=kafka
                  strimzi.io/controller=strimzipodset
                  strimzi.io/controller-name=logs-kafka
                  strimzi.io/kind=Kafka
                  strimzi.io/name=logs-kafka
                  strimzi.io/pod-name=logs-kafka-0
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 8cc6fa4c2358943a021a4f57118ea14aaa2b7ba90d82a83694cde4ef4ca171fb
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.233.103.77/32
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.233.103.77/32
                  strimzi.io/broker-configuration-hash: 31150f35
                  strimzi.io/clients-ca-cert-generation: 0
                  strimzi.io/cluster-ca-cert-generation: 0
                  strimzi.io/inter-broker-protocol-version: 2.8
                  strimzi.io/kafka-version: 3.4.0
                  strimzi.io/log-message-format-version: 2.8
                  strimzi.io/logging-appenders-hash: e893ac9f
                  strimzi.io/revision: ea7a75a0
Status:           Running
IP:               10.233.103.77
IPs:
  IP:           10.233.103.77
Controlled By:  StrimziPodSet/logs-kafka
Containers:
  kafka:
    Container ID:  containerd://c88afebad014f4ee674b26c2a3e1fa2422cbeccd32d29ccf0df00a2377d58c99
    Image:         quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.33.2-kafka-3.4.0
    Image ID:      quay.io/strimzi/kafka@sha256:40a847f8455ec6ea9ff9fe1fff20b1ed01f848326dc13977d13ac911f0cb40b7
    Ports:         9090/TCP, 9091/TCP, 9092/TCP, 9093/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Command:
      /opt/kafka/kafka_run.sh
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 02 Mar 2023 18:42:05 +0100
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Thu, 02 Mar 2023 18:41:44 +0100
      Finished:     Thu, 02 Mar 2023 18:42:05 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  144
    Limits:
      cpu:     12
      memory:  24Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      8
      memory:   16Gi
    Liveness:   exec [/opt/kafka/kafka_liveness.sh] delay=15s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  exec [/opt/kafka/kafka_readiness.sh] delay=15s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      KAFKA_METRICS_ENABLED:            false
      STRIMZI_KAFKA_GC_LOG_ENABLED:     false
      STRIMZI_DYNAMIC_HEAP_PERCENTAGE:  50
      STRIMZI_DYNAMIC_HEAP_MAX:         5368709120
    Mounts:
      /opt/kafka/broker-certs from broker-certs (rw)
      /opt/kafka/client-ca-certs from client-ca-cert (rw)
      /opt/kafka/cluster-ca-certs from cluster-ca (rw)
      /opt/kafka/custom-config/ from kafka-metrics-and-logging (rw)
      /tmp from strimzi-tmp (rw)
      /var/lib/kafka/data from data (rw)
      /var/opt/kafka from ready-files (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-798ml (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  data-logs-kafka-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  strimzi-tmp:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     Memory
    SizeLimit:  5Mi
  cluster-ca:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  logs-cluster-ca-cert
    Optional:    false
  broker-certs:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  logs-kafka-brokers
    Optional:    false
  client-ca-cert:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  logs-clients-ca-cert
    Optional:    false
  kafka-metrics-and-logging:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      logs-kafka-0
    Optional:  false
  ready-files:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     Memory
    SizeLimit:  1Ki
  kube-api-access-798ml:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                    From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                   ----     -------
  Normal   Pulled   18m (x139 over 9h)     kubelet  Container image "quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.33.2-kafka-3.4.0" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff  3m11s (x2390 over 9h)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container kafka in pod logs-kafka-0_logs(5bc2f7e4-968e-478c-a2e0-d075377b5f7f)
```

Someone already face this issue or have an idea to resolve it ?
Thanks

Comment: can you attach `kubectl describe pod/logs-kafka-0`  ?

Comment: Hi @Mahendran, that's done.

Comment: Warn logs are not why the kafka pods are crashing. The real error is in your previous post. If you have changed any configs, please edit that post